# How to return views upon Ajax requests in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Let me start off by saying I am a moderate at Laravel/JQuery so please bear with my question.

I would like to return a view when the user clicks a button, using ajax. Whenever I click the button, I receive no error but also do not get any html. Any help is appreciated.

**I defined my routes web.php as:**

```
Route::get('ajax', function() {
    return view('test');
});

Route::post('/getmsg', function() {
     $msg = "<strong>This is a simple message.</strong>";
     $returnHTML=view('form1_sections/section2_form')->render();
     return response()->json(array('html'=>$returnHTML, 'msg'=>$msg));
});
```

**My test.blade.php looks like:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Ajax Example</title>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        function getMessage() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/getmsg',
                data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#msg").html(data.html);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
        Click the button to replace the message.</div>
    <form>
        <button onclick="getMessage()">Replace Message</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**My section2_form view looks like:**

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

        <h4>Date of Previous Research Leave</h4>
        <br>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <label>
            <input class="form-control" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" type="date">
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <label>
            <input class="form-control" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="End Date" type="date">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(data)` inside success function?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `dataType` of your request to `json`. Also your construction of your `token` is, well it's not incorrect, but there's a better way, observe the following for the complete answer:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getmsg',
    data: {
        token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#msg").html(data.html);
    }
});
```

The reason it needs to be `json` is otherwise the request assumes the response is `text/html`. This means that it won't call `JSON.parse()` on the returned data, so you won't have an object that you can access properties from.

Comment: No luck :/ it does not load anything.

Comment: Remove dataType from request. it will resolve as i was stuck in same problem but when i commented dataType than it console whole HTML.In controller use
**return view('form1_sections/section2_form');**